Battery issues Toyota yaris
My battery keeps draining every few days  it’s virtually new & the alternator is working as it’s pumping 12-13 volts every time check it…my reversing lights have stopped working upon inspection I find they are only getting 5-6 volts too the bulbs..could they be shorting out some how & draining the battery…
